# Automating Actions in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, html-email, office-automation

I have a folder of emails in outlook, and I want to be able to apply the same action to each email within the folder, however I notice that there is no macro recorder within Outlook's Developer options.

The process that I am currently undertaking involves opening each email (as it contains HTML content and I want to print it in a document quality image) selecting "View in browser" from the "Actions" tab, and printing from Internet Explorer.

Is there a way to iterate this action within Outlook for each email within the folder? I have no clue as to how to set about this without some way of recording my actions to get an idea of how to refer to things within the Outlook module...

Comment: Outlook does not have a recorder.  You have to type the VBA yourself (or copy it off the internet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to learn a little bit about Outlook's Object model [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Here is a little code to get you started. This macro will loop through all the items in a folder and check the email address of the recipient and set the flag

```
Sub SetFlagIcon()
    Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim obj As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Integer
    Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Jeanno").Folders("Sent Mail")
    ' Loop all items in the Inbox\Test Folder
    For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count
        If mpfInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
            Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i)
            For Each Recipient In obj.Recipients
                If Recipient.Address = "someone@email" Then
                    'Set the yellow flag icon
                    obj.FlagIcon = olYellowFlagIcon
                    obj.Save
                End If
            Next Recipient
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't have a macro recorder, but you can use the macros recorded in Word Since Outlook use Microsoft Word as Email editor that allows developers to use the powerful library of Word to edit the content of Emails and other items.

You can record a macro in Word and use the same code in the Outlook VBA project, just make sure to set reference to the "*Microsoft Word Object Library*" so Outlook can recognize the objects used by Word.

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub UseWord()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Word As Word.Application
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection

    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set wDoc = Ins.WordEditor
    Set Word = wDoc.Application
    Set Selection = Word.Selection

    'insert here your macro from word

End Sub
```

Here is helpful Link [Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)